# /etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 43: Bad configuration option: StrictHostKeyChecking

Tags: centos, sshd

My `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` set StrictHostKeyChecking = no then can not started:

```
StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

My sshd version is:

```
[root@localhost ~]# sshd --version
unknown option -- -
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
usage: sshd [-46DdeiqTt] [-C connection_spec] [-c host_cert_file]
            [-E log_file] [-f config_file] [-g login_grace_time]
            [-h host_key_file] [-o option] [-p port] [-u len]
```

with the error:

```
Sep 23 04:32:47 localhost sshd: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: line 43: Bad configuration option: StrictHostKeyChecking
Sep 23 04:32:47 localhost sshd: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
Sep 23 04:32:47 localhost systemd: sshd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Sep 23 04:32:47 localhost systemd: Failed to start OpenSSH server daemon.
Sep 23 04:32:47 localhost systemd: Unit sshd.service entered failed state.
Sep 23 04:32:47 localhost systemd: sshd.service failed.
```

My Server is CentOS 7.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is an option from `ssh_config` (note there is no d)

```
man ssh_config
```

> StrictHostKeyChecking
> If this flag is set to yes, ssh(1) will never automatically
> add host keys to the ~/.ssh/known_hosts

you check host key when you connect, not when receiving incomming connection.